# Two different counts in the one query

Tags: mysql

I have a web page that displays requests received by each user (Firstname) that are separated into 1 of 4 lists based on 4 separate queries which rely on a `WHERE` statement to check the value of the ‘`status`’ column (`incoming,` `playlisted, sidelisted, played`).

This solution works for the ‘played’ list.

```
SELECT
    t1.FirstName, count(*)
FROM
    RequestsTable t1
WHERE t1.status = 'played'
GROUP BY t1.FirstName;
```

but the WHERE statement doesn’t allow it to work for requests that are in the other 3 lists.

Two counts are required within each of the 4 lists to show

i) the total number of requests made by each user.

ii) the number of requests made by each user that have been ’played’.

All of my attempts to use JOINS and CASE statements have been defeated by the WHERE statement which limits the counts to the records within any 1 of the 4 lists.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the WHERE statement and put the status conditions in the COUNT:

```
SELECT
    t1.FirstName, 
    count(*) as totalCount, 
    count(IF(t1.status = 'played',1,null)) as playedCount
FROM
    RequestsTable t1
GROUP BY t1.FirstName;
```

Comment: Thanks Vatev. But the WHERE is needed to correctly populate the four separate lists, isn't it?

Comment: I don't know what "the lists" should look like :) It would help if you show an example result

Comment: Hi. There are four lists populated by 'status' ('incoming', 'playlisted', 'sidelisted', 'played'). All four lists should return 'Firstname', 'Request details', 'count of requests per user', 'count of requests played per user'

Comment: @user3317371: Then use a left join instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    t1.FirstName, count(*) cnt ,0  played,0 played2 
FROM
    RequestsTable t1
GROUP BY t1.FirstName
union
SELECT
    t1.FirstName, 0 cnt ,count(*)  played,0 played2
FROM
    RequestsTable t1
    WHERE t1.status = 'played'
GROUP BY t1.FirstName
union
SELECT
    t1.FirstName, 0 cnt,0 played ,count(*)  played2
FROM
    RequestsTable t1
    WHERE t1.status = 'played2'
GROUP BY t1.FirstName
```

Try above query.
Hope this will helps.

Comment: This slightly amended query so nearly works, but I get repeat results depending on the counts?

Comment: FirstName cnt played played2 status 
freddy 2 0 0  played 
Geraldine 2 0 0 played 
graham  1 0 0  sidelisted 
harry 1 0 0  playlisted 
Jimmy 1 0 0  incoming 
mickie 2 0 0  played 
freddy 0 2 0  played 
Geraldine 0 2 0 played 
mickie 0 2 0  played

Comment: Sorry - not helpful, the above, Screenshot here http://pinknoise.biz/images/Capture.PNG

Comment: @user3317371 what it is returning?